Why am I having this error with Gradle plugin?
I have been trying to resolve this issue for several days now I have tried nearly every solution including the instructions on the android site:
I keep having this error:

This is what my plugins look like in my settings.gradle file:

I have even updated the gradle wrapper properties too but still the same error

Please include text as text, not as images.
